# Reference book of Abstract Algebra - view with teaching and research

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

There are continuously publishing the books of Abstract Algebra.

For the question purpose: let us say "Modern Books" to the books came in print after year 2000.

The modern books, written by new generation of mathematicians and researchers cover the topics of  Herstein,  Fraleigh, Gallian etc.

But, in many books of Abstract Algebra, nothing more than content of these old books it is said except "detailed explanation" or "different explanation".

Can one suggest some modern books on Abstract Algebra which includes (each of the) following:

- Cover (most of) the material in Herstein, Fraleigh, Gallian (such old texts).
- Include new topics, essential for research in new branches of algebra
- Includes the tricky challenging exercises on all topics.
- Touches some topics for very current research in algebra

Comment: The book [Algebra](https://www.amazon.de/Algebra-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics-Band/dp/038795385X) from Serge Lang, published $2002$ is just modern by your definition, but has famously challenging exercises, and touches many research topics. For very recent research topics it may not be the right place to find them in a standard book on abstract algebra, because the research nowadays is very advanced and technical.

Comment: [Algebra: Chapter 0](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-104) should be a good match.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde: The 2002 Lang book is a reprint of the 1993 edition, and I suspect that edition is little changed from the edition used in a 2-semester graduate algebra sequence I took during the 1977-1978 academic year. However, what you've said about it definitely fits my experience! Several years later, at another university (this time as a graduate student), I had a couple of courses out of [Hungerford's book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387905189), which was much more didactically written and most of the exercises were fairly straightforward.